# Execute a command in a separate file

Tags: c++, batch-file, embed

Is it possible to store a "command" in a separate file, and have it called whenever you input the name of that file?

Let's say: file `help` contains code: `cout << "This is help file.";`
So is it possible to get the content of file without need of creating a functions in it, straight to action, like it is in Lua?

> Edit

Well, I'm in the process of learning the C++ so embedding Lua won't make sense for me, yet that's a very good idea for my future projects, thank you.

What i'm trying to do is a simulation of command line os. Something like ComputerCraft. Basically you type in a command, the program then, looks for a actual file with same name as user's input and if found executes it's content. It is all done in runtime, check for file, execution, adding new etc.

Something like
In console:

```
> help
```

Program checks for the file named help and if found executes it
Contents of `help`:

```
cout << "type help for help, programs for list of programs etc";
```

I want it that way to make it possible to create a new "command" file right from that simulated os and automatically make it usable with least effort possible for user.

I did it in lua before and I would like to know how and if it's possible in C++
I was working in Love2D, and it has a function `love.filesystem.load(filename)` basically what it does, it creates a function which has the content of the file as it's container, you assign it a name `function = love.filesystem.load(filename)` and then execute it as a normal function. What I'm seeking for is equivalent of it.

Comment: Are you asking if you can execute C++ code in a text file at runtime? (The answer is no, unless you carry a C++ compiler with your program or invent an interpreter)

Comment: You need to store  that code *somewhere*. In a function/lambda/etc... You can add that wrapperlayer in *another* file, then `#include` the file from there... that is, if that makes you happy. I don't really see the point of doing it.

Comment: @VictorSavcenco: C++ is not a scripting language, but I would anyway doubt that you would really need such scripting language features in your program. Maybe you paint a little bigger picture and tell about the use case for that.

Comment: If you love Lua so much, why don't you just embed a Lua VM in your C++ program? That's what it's made for after all.

Comment: You probably want `dlopen` or `LoadLibrary` depending on your platform (note: not standard C++). There's a wrapper that can be helpful for plugin systems: libltdl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute a script in a file, you will either need to use an existing scripting language and include an interpreter in your program, or invent your own scripting language and code how to interpret it.

If you want the files to contain C++ code to be executed at run-time, this is impossible or so you will be told. Actually it's not impossible; people who tell you that are technically wrong. But it is insanely difficult and definitely not a beginner's project.

You will either need to include a fully-fledged C++ compiler in your program, compile the code in the file at run-time and execute the result. Some virus scanners can get unhappy when a program tries to do that. (Sometimes my one complains about my creations in Visual Studio!)

Or you will need a run-time C++ interpreter. If such a thing exists, I would be very interested to know about it!

Practically speaking the best you could hope for is an interpreter that can work with a very limited subset of C++.

Comment: [CINT](https://root.cern.ch/cint)? Interpeters certainly exist. I doubt they're a good solution for the OP though.

Comment: @Flexo And do these run ALL standard C++ or just a subtset of it?

Comment: So, C++ is static type of language, right? On contrary to Lua which is more flexible, if I understand right. I think I understand. So my options would be to embed another language for that purpose?

Comment: @VictorSavcenco C++ is designed from the ground up to be a compiled language. So although a 100% interpreter is not technically impossible, it is too difficult to produce in practice, as far as I am aware

Comment: I see, so for those kind of tasks it's better to embed a scripting language, which was done in Minecraft for ComputerCraft with LUA, I suppose. Thank you for answer.